# Calculating total price using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I made a little form to test some things in, but i've come across a little problem i don't really know how to solve.

I made input fields and a price  that changes when the user inputs a different number using javascript, which looks like this:

```
function changeTotalFromCount(input) {
    var unitPrice = parseFloat(input.getAttribute("data-unitPrice"));
    var count = input.value;

    var price = unitPrice * count;
    var formattedPrice = '\u20ac ' + price.toFixed(2);

    var label = input.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    label.innerHTML = '';
    if (count != ''){
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formattedPrice));
    } else {
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
    }
}
```

I have around 10 products in my form which i take out of my array like this:

```
<?php foreach($productsData as $productData):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $productData['product']?></td>
        <td>&#8364; <?php echo $productData['price']?></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="count<?php echo $productData['code']?>" class="formnumbers" name="<?php echo $productData['name']?>" onChange="validateForm(this);changeTotalFromCount(this);" min="1" max="99"  data-unitprice="<?php echo $productData['price']?>"/></td>
        <td><span id="total<?php echo $productData['code']?>"></span></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

My array looks like this:

```
<?php
    $productsData = array(
        array( 'product' => 'Pizza Margherita',         'code' => 'Margherita',         'name' => 'PizzaMargherita',        'price' => '7.00'),
        array( 'product' => 'Pizza Fungi',              'code' => 'Fungi',              'name' => 'PizzaFungi',             'price' => '8.00'),
        array( 'product' => 'Pizza Hawai',              'code' => 'Hawai',              'name' => 'PizzaHawai',             'price' => '9.00'),
        array( 'product' => 'Pizza QuattroStagioni',    'code' => 'QuattroStagioni',    'name' => 'PizzaQuattroStagioni',   'price' => '11.00'),
        array( 'product' => 'Pizza Calzone',            'code' => 'Calzone',            'name' => 'PizzaCalzone',           'price' => '13.00'),
        array( 'product' => 'Broodje Shoarma',          'code' => 'BroodjeShoarma',     'name' => 'BroodjeShoarma',         'price' => '5.00'),
        array( 'product' => 'Broodje Doner',            'code' => 'BroodjeDoner',       'name' => 'BroodjeDoner',           'price' => '5.50'),
        array( 'product' => 'Durum Doner',              'code' => 'DurumDoner',         'name' => 'DurumDoner',             'price' => '6.00'),
        array( 'product' => 'Knoflook Saus',            'code' => 'KnoflookSaus',       'name' => 'KnoflookSaus',           'price' => '0.50'),
        array( 'product' => 'Whiskey Saus',             'code' => 'WhiskeySaus',        'name' => 'WhiskeySaus',            'price' => '0.50'),
        array( 'product' => 'Sambal Saus',              'code' => 'SambalSaus',         'name' => 'SambalSaus',             'price' => '0.50')
     );
?>
```

This works all fine, but i need a total price, which will display at the bottom, and when the user say adds 1 product that costs $ 7.00 it will say 7, but when the user order 2 products that cost $ 10.00 it will change to $ 27.00

I hope i made my question clear, if not please tell me!

A small JSFiddle so you understand whats happeneing: http://jsfiddle.net/ygHSC/

In this example i didn't take out all my products with my array but i hope you get what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a method with some kind of a loop over all your input fields, just like the one you created for one field, and trigger the call each time one field is updated:

```
function getTotalPrice() {
  var total = 0,
      inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].value) {
      total += parseFloat(inputs[i].getAttribute("data-unitPrice")) * 
               parseInt(inputs[i].value,10);
    }
  }
  if(total > 0) {
    document.getElementById('TARGET').innerText = '\u20ac ' + total.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

An updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ygHSC/3/).

Comment: You fiddle works exactly as i want to, however i  can't get it to work inside my own website. I added the getTotalprice(); to the changeTotalFromCount(input) and added the entire function you made. I also added the id to the total price here. Weird...

Comment: Any kind of JS-Error? Any chance, that you can post an URL to have a look at it?

Comment: As you can see my `ChangeTotalFromCount()` looks different then the one im using in the jsfiddle too.

Something other usefull to mention is that i have 5 more input fields in the form but those are not for products but for name adres, etc.

Comment: well this is one of the reasons, you must filter the fields (either by a classname, or a container id). In case you can't proceed from there , provide an updated fiddle.

Comment: Yes it works fine now thanks, only problem left is that it starts with an empty field (which is good) and if i add 1 it will go to 7 (which is also good) but when i empty all fields it stays on 7.

Comment: Sigh, im stupid just added a quick else innertext = '' and it works fine now! Thanks again for your help and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Take each total and add each time and put it in the place of TOtal price,

Comment: You should be adding proper content if you are to post as answer, else just leave as a comment..

Comment: How exactly would that look like using my code? Since i don't really have an idea how to do this. I get the theory but using my code i'm getting a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `change` events to update a variable for each of the inputs, and make a small separate function to add them together and return the total.

Comment: The theory is clear, but Using my code with the arrays and all the javascript i'm getting confused, can you explain a bit more what you mean or push me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: You have an event listener checking for the inputs changing. When the input is changed, it takes the value of the input, multiplies it by the unit price, and calls a totalling function. The totalling function simply adds the two subtotals together, and sets the text of whatever element you want to show that total appropriately.